# What does "communion of the Holy Spirit" mean in 2 Corinthians 13:14?

Tags: 2-corinthians, pneumatology

What does **communion of the Holy Spirit** mean in

> [2 Corinthians 13:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%2013:14&version=NKJV) The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ, and the
>   love of God, and the **communion** **of the Holy Spirit** be with you all.

Comment: Please show on your Q's and A's what Bibles you're using. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnMartin, Ok, The reference link  in my quote of scripture also reveals the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Corinthians 13:14’s words “communion of the Holy Spirit” help complete the Apostle’s belief in the Blessed Trinity. The verse’s previous words include “The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ, and the love of God..” (2 Cor 13:14 Darby)

When St. Thomas Aquinas explained 2 Cor 13-14, he chose to include verses 11 through 14.

> **2 Corinthians 13:11-14 (Darby)**
>
> 11 For the rest, brethren, rejoice; be perfected; be encouraged; be of one mind; be at peace; and the God of love and peace shall be with you. 12 Salute one another with a holy kiss. 13 All the saints salute you. 14 The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ, and the love of God, and the communion of the Holy Spirit, [be] with you all.

St. Thomas Aquinas's [commentary on 2 Cor 13](https://sites.google.com/site/aquinasstudybible/home/2-corinthians/st-thomas-aquinas-on-2-corinthians/chapter-1/chapter-2/chapter-3/chapter-4/chapter-5/chapter-6/chapter-7/chapter-8/chapter-9/chapter-10/chapter-11/chapter-12/chapter-13):

> **544** ... “God shows his love for us” (Rom. 5:8), he attributes charity to him as to its source, when he says, and the love of God, namely, the Father. Finally, the communication of divine gifts is accomplished by the Holy Spirit: “All these are inspired by one and the same Spirit” (1 Cor. 12:11). Therefore he attributes communication to the Holy Spirit, when he says, and the fellowship [participation] of the Holy Spirit. Or, he attributes this to him because he is common to the other two persons.
>
> **545** Thus therefore the Apostle in his greeting wishes them all things that are necessary when he says: The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ and the love of God and the fellowship of the Holy Spirit be with you all. The grace of Christ, by which we are made just and are saved; the charity of God the Father, by which we are united to him; and the fellowship of the Holy Spirit distributing divine gifts to us. Amen.

Comment: Thank you :-) Does that men talking with the Holy Spirit? as in a conversation with a person?

Comment: That would depend on your own perspective. If you consider the Holy Spirit part of the Trinity and thus God, then you might consider talking with God. Note: St. Thomas Aquinas saw the Holy Spirit as "common to the other two persons."

Comment: Could you please provide the source of St. Thomas Aquinas

Comment: Sure. It's from his work in the link above... https://dhspriory.org/thomas/SS2Cor.htm

Answer (score 1):

Communion of the Spirit is also mentioned in Aramaic Bible in Plain English

> Philippians 2:1 If you have, therefore, comfort in The Messiah, or the filling up of hearts with love, or communion of The Spirit, or tender care and mercy, 2 Fulfill my joy, that you would have **one** conscience, **one** love, **one** soul and **one** mind;

It refers to the indwelling Holy Spirit in our spirit to accomplish oneness with God.

Answer (score -1):

What does communion of the Holy Spirit mean in 2 Corinthians 13:14?

There are several points to consider;

1. It's **communion** (or fellowship) **of**, not with. There is no attribute of 'person' here. There is a firm understanding as reiterated in many places of the work that is done by God *through* His spirit in believers to have love and care for one another - communion within the body of the son by the spirit. There is no communion without the spirit of God working/dwelling in us.
2. The spirit and Jesus is mentioned and 'God' too - which is quite UNtrinitarian - unless one does some crafty eisegesis with the text. God is not Father son and spirit here - just God who is the Father, shown to be quite distinct from Jesus and the Spirit - just as the NT consistently tells us.
3. We can readily see that God does things *through* His spirit. Take the birth of Jesus for eg. The apparent reading without making things up is for God to be Jesus' father, not the Holy Spirit - even though, 'she was found to be pregnant through the Holy Spirit' Matt 1:18. And while there are pages telling the same truth, it is God who is at work calling and granting repentance to His children - placing His spirit in us so that we may be sons. 'God has sent forth the Spirit of His Son into our hearts', Gal 4:6 and

> John 14:23 Jesus answered and said to him, If any one love me, he will
> keep my word, and my Father will love him, and **we will come** to him and
> make our abode with him.

Comment: This is fairly unabashed theological squirming - Paul simple discussed three persons; end of story.  See also Acts 2:33, 10:38, Rom 1:2-4, 8:9, 15:30, 1 Cor 6:11, 12:2-6 (inter alia) all mention three people.

Comment: Thanks very much for a list of scriptures that you read '3 people' into - while ignoring all evidence to the contrary. No surprises there. The spirit OF God and OF the son still has no name... end of story indeed! I'm just presenting the facts - no need to make anything up from extra-biblical sources or from corrupted texts to support unbiblical constructs.